Number of $m\times n$ matrices of rank $0\leq k\leq min\{m,n\}$
I am studying the enumeration of $m$-by-$n$ matrices over a finite field $F_q$ with a specific rank $r$. I came across a post that describes the number of such matrices using the formulas given in the following question.
Number of $k\times n$ matrices of rank $k$
In there, two equivalent expressions (1) and (2) give the number of $m$-by-$n$ matrices over $F_q$ of rank $r$ as follows:
$\left( \prod_{j=1}^r (q^m - q^{j-1}) \right) \sum_{j_1, \dots, j_r \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}} q^{\sum_{i=1}^r i j_i}, \quad \text{with the constraint} \sum_{i=1}^r j_i \leq n-r$
$\left( \prod_{j=1}^r (q^n - q^{j-1}) \right) \sum_{j_1, \dots, j_r \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}} q^{\sum_{i=1}^r i j_i}, \quad \text{with the constraint} \sum_{i=1}^r j_i \leq m-r$
Moreover, these expressions are simplified to a product form in the following:
$\prod_{j=1}^r \frac{(q^m - q^{j-1})(q^n - q^{j-1})}{q^{j-1}(q^j - 1)}
$
My questions are:

The part $\sum_{j_1, \dots, j_r \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}} q^{\sum_{i=1}^r i j_i}$ is confusing to me, especially how the summation indices and the exponential part contribute to the count of matrices.

How the two expression converted to $\prod_{j=1}^r \frac{(q^m - q^{j-1})(q^n - q^{j-1})}{q^{j-1}(q^j - 1)}
$
? I also saw the post below, but I couldn't understand the process by which the equation was derived.
Algebraic or Analytic Proof of a Polynomial Identity


I understand, except for these two parts.
Thank you.
